# Finding the number at a specific index of spirally filled matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

The problem is as follows:

We have 3 integer values as input: n, i, j
Suppose we have n × n matrix, that is filled with numbers from 1 to n² in clockwise spiral way. Find the number at the index (i, j).

I know how to construct such matrix, I can solve it by filling the matrix and looking at the index (i, j), and I consider such solution a bit too "brute force". I believe there should be some mathematical relationship between the number n, the indices i, j and the number sitting at that cell. I've tried some approaches but couldn't find a way to do it. Any suggestions to help me in my attempt?

Edit: an example 5x5 matrix:

```
1  2  3  4  5 
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9
```

Comment: Much depends on how exactly this spiral starts. Can you include a matrix of about 5x5 to take away any ambiguity?

Comment: @trincot Yes, forgot to include an example array, edited the post

Comment: And i and j both are in the range (0..n-1)? And (0, 0) is the top-left with content 1?

Comment: @trincot Yes exactly, just like a regular 2D array. For example i=4 j=3 would correspond to number 10

Comment: @CIKAcademy i=3; j=4 is 10 right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with some basic arithmetic (assuming 0-based indexing, `i` stands for the row and `j` for the column):

1. Find the ring in which the number is in. It is `r = min(i, j, n - i - 1, n - j - 1)`. This is counting the rings from outer to inner. If we count from inside to outside (which will come in handy later), then we get `q = (n - 1) / 2 - r` for odd `n` or `q = (n - 2) / 2 - r` for even `n`. Or generalized: `q = (n - 2 + n % 2) / 2 - r` which is the same as `q = (n - 1) / 2 - r` for integer division (as mentioned by [@Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef)).
2. It is not that hard to see that the number of elements covered by a ring (including the numbers inside of it) from most inner  going outwards is 1^2, 3^2, 5^2, ... if n is odd and 2^2, 4^2, 6^2, ... if n is even. So the side length of the square covered by ring `q` is (in generalized form) `m = q * 2 + 2 - n % 2`. This means the element in the upper left corner of the ring is `b = n^2 - m^2 + 1`.
3. Get the number:

   1. If `r == i`: `b + j - r` (element is on top side).
   2. If `r == n - j - 1`: `b + m - 1 + i - r` (element is on the right side)
   3. If `r == n - i - 1`: `b + 2 * m - 2 + n - j - 1 - r` (element is on the bottom)
   4. Otherwise (`r == j`): `b + 3 * m - 3 + n - i - 1 - r` (element is on the left side)

This is O(1). The formulas can be simplified, but then the explanation would be harder to understand.

Example: n = 5, i = 3, j = 2

1. r = min(2, 3, 1, 2) = 1, q = (3 + 1) / 2 - 1 = 1
2. m = 2 + 2 - 1 = 3, b = 25 - 9  + 1 = 17
3. Third condition applies: 17 + 6 - 2 + 5 - 2 - 1 - 1 = 22

Comment: If `//` is integer division, then `q = (n - 1) // 2 - r` is equal to `(n - 1) / 2 - r` for odd n and `(n - 2) / 2 - r` for even n.

Comment: if `n` is odd, then `(n-1)` is even.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. I was just pointing out that the formula `q = (n - 2 + n % 2) / 2 - r` is equivalent to the formula `q = (n - 1) // 2 - r`.

Comment: @Stef you are right, i made an error. Edited my answer.